# $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that for a commutative ring to be an integral domain is the cancellation law holds. But how to approach to prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ is an integral domain ?

Comment: Hint: If a $R$ is a commutative ring with unity, and $I$ is an ideal, then the ring $R/I$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal.

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ (it has degree $2$ and no rational roots), so the ideal $I=(x^2+1)$ is maximal. In particular $I$ is a prime ideal, which implies that $\mathbb Q[x]/I$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is a very good general tool, that you should become familiar with. But if you don't have the necessary theorems yet, here's a hands-on approach.

We show that $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field, hence definitely an integral domain. Given an arbitrary element in this ring, it has a representative of the form $a + bx$. By an application of the Hindsight Theorem*, we claim the inverse is $\frac{a - bx}{a^2 + b^2}$:
$$ (a + bx) \frac{a - bx}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{a^2 - b^2 x^2}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2 + b^2} = 1 $$

---

*The intuition here is that, because $x^2 = -1$ in this ring, $x$ should behave very much like the imaginary $i$, and so we use our knowledge of complex numbers to come up with the formula for the inverse.

Comment: If you didn't have complex numbers or hindsight, you could still get the formula for the reciprocal by "rationalizing the denominator" in $\frac1{a+bx}$. You don't need to know that $x$ is "like the complex number $i$", just that it's something that you don't want in the denominator.